ZeroMQ Binary Star pattern ( for high availability )
Reading the ZeroMQ Guide I stumbled upon some part of the text that I don't understand very well. This is in Chapter 4, Reliable Request-Reply Patterns, specifically Binary Star pattern.

A suitably paranoid network configuration would use two private
cluster interconnects, rather than a single one. Further, the network
cards used for the cluster would be different from those used for
message traffic, and possibly even on different paths on the server
hardware. The goal is to separate possible failures in the network
from possible failures in the cluster. Network ports can have a
relatively high failure rate.

What's a private cluster interconnect in this case? What does it mean that network cards are in different paths on the server hardware? How would one do this in aws more or less?


Q1 :"What's a private cluster interconnect in this case?"

Any kind of physically separate ( not to re-introduce anti-pattern of a new singularity into a fail-safe design ) interconnection - a dedicated cable, less commonly a Carrier Service, a network-tunneling path, an IrDA or a dedicated WLL OTA connection between computing nodes, that form together the private ( non-public, not shared ) computing cluster.

Q2 :"What does it mean that network cards are in different paths on the server hardware?"

As an example one might imagine one NIC be an onboard integrated card, another being a PCI-hosted NIC, another a USB-3 hosted NIC - simply to have still more fail-safe paths for cases some relatively local hardware failures started to degrade the basic operations and a cluster node turned into somewhat reduced levels of operations, yet still having some functional paths to/from its network interconnects.

Q3 :"How would one do this in aws more or less?"

Since initial motivation for marketing a mass use of AWS hosted services was to "share" things, in exchange for paying less than owning one's own infrastructure, no one can "do this in aws" ( without paying for any extra arrangements to finally get almost a private ( AWS operated as non-shared - here "measure twice before cut once" as evidence might show some hidden cut corners ) computing node, the more a private ( AWS installed, operated & maintained ) cluster ).
Even respectable academia institutions have found themselves to finally pay way more for AWS "emulated" infrastructure, than their originally CAPEX invested into their private HW, on campus DataCentre altogether with their OPEX costs ( only to realise their "move" into Cloud was more expensive, hard to reverse, not speaking about "human capital" lost, and fatally less performant and almost un-manageable, than their original private on-campus cluster computing ).
Facts matter.
Always.

Thank you so much for your answer. I think what I was trying to ask in my question is how would one deploy binary star servers for high availability in aws in modern times. Not that it has to be private or anything.
And the first question would be better phrased as: How would the network look like simply in the case where its dedicated for the binary star and different for general traffic as the guide mentions?
